# Semivariance: Are these two formulas equivalent?

Tags: variance, variogram

Mean Semivariance optimization defines semivariance, variance only below the benchmark/required rate of return, as:

$$\frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T [\min(R_{it}-B,0)]^2$$

where $B$ is the benchmark rate, $R_i$ is the asset returns for asset $i$, and $T$ is the number of observations.

Post Modern Portfolio theory however, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-modern_portfolio_theory), defines downside risk (which according to my understanding should be equal to semivariance), as :

$$ \sqrt {\int_{-\infty}^t ({t-r})^2 f(r) \, dr}$$

where $t$ is the benchmark here, $r$ is the random variable representing the return for the distribution of annual returns $f(r)$, and $f(r)$ is the distribution for the annual returns.

Assuming $t$  is equal to $B$, would these two be equal, and can anyone prove so(not necessarily mathematically, intuitively would suffice)?

I know one is discrete and other continuous, so for a very large number of $T$ would these two be roughly equal?

Comment: Apart from the absence of the square root (which doesn't belong anywhere in a discussion of semivariance), the first formula is a special case of the second.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. And my bad, I suppose the second one would be semi deviation. Since you seem to be an expert in stats, I have another question: Are you aware of any R packages for calculating semi-covariance?

Comment: I am not aware of any, but the first search I would do is on the keywords "semivariance CRAN."  You have to eliminate the geostatistical hits.  After doing that on Google I find this: https://rdrr.io/cran/PerformanceAnalytics/man/DownsideDeviation.html.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I had already come across Performance Analytics. Anyways, thank you for the assistance.